how to make imagebackground cover the phone botom notch in expo react native with react navigation
enter image description here
im try to cover the entire screen with an image,the code below ony covers the status bar only, i want it to cover the entire screen event the bottom notch.im wondering if there us other way to do it or if im doing something wrong
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  ImageBackground,
} from "react-native";


const Welcome = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.screenContainer}>
      <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
      >
      </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screenContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor:"red"
  }
})

const Stack= () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default function App() {enter image description here

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


Instead of flex, try using the height of the screen for this. You can find the height using Dimensions from react-native. const {height, width} = Dimensions.get("screen")

yes setting height equal to the screen dimenstion increase the image height to cover the bottom notch but still the image is not visible because the bottom notch has a color or some other reason and yes i tried to make to change bottom notch color to transparent
